How to set time zone in Rails 5.2 to 3:30 instead of 4:30 for Iran
It has been 2 years since the time in Iran hasn't changed during the spring. It used to change from 3:30 to 4:30 in the first of spring, but these years, it hasn't changed. So, I want my time zone to be set to 3:30, not 4:30.
My Ruby version is 2.6.5 and my Rails version is 5.2.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

You don't set UTC offsets directly. Instead you provide a time zone by name and let the system figure out the current offset. Rails' time zone definitions come from the tzinfo and tzinfo-data gems. Updating these should provide recent time zone data.

Which version of tzinfo are you using? According to my quick research, the changes to Iran's timezones were announced as part of the 2022b timezone data, which was added to the ruby gem here and released in tzinfo-data version 1.2022.2, on August 11, 2022.

I don't think the version of ruby or rails is relevant here.

@Stefan tzinfo-data is not actually required on most unix systems as they have a zoneinfo directory.

Thanks to all of you, I installed tzdata (apt install tzdata) in the Debian Docker image, and this bug is now fixed.

I fixed the problem by installing the tzdata package in Debian using the command:
apt install tzdata

